# Maximization using partial derivatives?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A trough is to be formed by bending up two sides of a long metal rectangle so that the cross-section of the trough is an isosceles trapezoid. If the width of the metal sheet is 2 meters, how should it be bent to maximize the volume of the trough

I honestly do not know how to start. I know that I have to do partials but I do not know...

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to maximise the cross sectional area not the volume.
If the sides of the trapezoid are $x$ and they are bent to an angle $\alpha$ from the vertical then the cross-sectional area is given by $A(x,\alpha)=x^2 \cos (\alpha)\sin(\alpha)+(2-2 x)x \cos(\alpha)$.
From here just calculate the partials w.r.t. $x$ and $\alpha$ and solve.

I found it easiest to use the partial wrt $x$ to get an expression for $\sin(\alpha)$ in terms of $x$, and then substitute this back into the partial wrt $\alpha$ which gives you an equation in $x$ alone.